# Pycharm debug process drops to console instead of exiting

Tags: python, pycharm

My pycharm debugs sessions have started dropping to a python console instead of exiting when the process is finished. Is there a setting somewhere to fix this?

```
pydev debugger: process 32230 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 193.6494.30)
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux

>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try:

`Run -> Edit Configurations -> Open the "Templates" in the left side -> Python -> Configuration -> Execution -> deselect "Run with Python Console"`

Or you maybe can create a new project to run your code.